# RE: Why am I getting the wrong value of vowels from this counter?... original code

Tags: c++

Instructions:
using a value returning function
Write a program that prompts the user to input a sequence of characters and outputs the number of vowels.
This is the problem given by the instructor..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isVowel(char ch);
int main() {
    char ch;
    cout << "Enter a character: ";
    cin >> ch;

    cout << ch << " is a vowel: " << isVowel(ch) << endl; 
    return 0;
}
bool isVowel(char ch){
    if (ch=='A' || ch=='E' || ch=='I' || ch=='O' || ch=='U' ||
        ch=='a' || ch=='e' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u'){
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: It is undefined behavior: `vowels;` is used without being initialized.

Comment: You're assigning the return value from `isVowel` to `ch` rather than `vowels`.

Comment: There's so many things wrong with this code.

Comment: I reassigned but I'm not getting any errors but the return in vowels is too high. What should I do to change it?

Comment: I think one of your problems is your teacher has likely not taught you a string in `c++` is `std::string`. Instead you were probably taught about character arrays but instead of an array you just used a single char.

Comment: I'm going to assume that I'm just not grasping the material. I'm taking an late start online class in which we are using Cengage and MindTap for the textbook, material, and exercises.

Comment: The code probably should be rolled back to the original version since the answers now don't make sense with the question. Remember the purpose of StackOverflow  is to help future readers with the same problem. StackOverflow is not a user support forum.

Answer (score 2):

`char` is a single character, not a sentence. For a sentence use a `string`.

```
string s;
cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
cin >> s;
```

Then use a loop to loop through each character of the sentence

```
for (char ch : s)
{
    ...
}
```

Then use `isVowel` to test a single character, and increment the count if found. The clue is in the name `isVowel`, not `countVowels`, so `isVowel` should test a single vowel and return true or false, not count the number of vowels.

```
int vowels = 0;
for (char ch : s)
{
     if (isVowel(ch))
         vowels++;
}
```

finally write `isVowel` to test a single character.

```
bool isVowel(char ch)
{ 
    return ch=='A' || ch=='E' || ch=='I' || ch=='O' || ch=='U' ||
        ch=='a' || ch=='e' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u';
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see where I went wrong in the modification of the original code. I'm going to edit my original post for a better understanding

Comment: You could also write code with `countVowels`, but it would need to not return a `bool`.

Comment: @BrandonWadeTaylor Please don't edit the post. People will try to help you with your code as it is in the post. If that changes, things will be confusing: you don't know what version of the code they saw, future readers will have even less idea, etc.

Comment: @DanielH I'm sorry I modified the original post. I'm new to this website and I'm not sure how to navigate. I tried uploading something else but another user removed it because it wasn't technically an "answer" (which I understand).

Comment: @DanielH If you want to change the code, then **add** the changed to the question (making it clear that it's an edit). But don't change what you already posted as that's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here.

Firstly, you don't initialize vowels. You presumably mean `int vowels = 0;` or `int vowels {0};`.

Secondly, you are reading a single character with `cin >> ch;`. I suspect you mean to loop over an input string.

Thirdly, your signature for `isVowel` is `bool isVowel(int vowels, char ch);`, which returns a bool. But you have written your function as thought it is manipulating an integer total of vowels. This inconsistency doesn't make sense.

Fourthly, you assign the result of `isVowel` to a character in `ch = isVowel(vowels,ch);`. Then you call `isVowel` again *with this updated `ch`* in `cout << isVowel(vowels, ch) << ...`. I'm not sure what you're attempting to do here, but this also doesn't make any sense.

You need to revisit all of this code. You probably want `isVowel` to actually return a boolean. You probably want to iterate over an entire input string, and adjust the value of `vowels` appropriately (after initializing it).

Answer (score 0):

Your program is running an undefined behavior; you are using `vowels` without being initialized.

You can make function that takes the counter of vowels as a reference to an integer for example.

```
void isVowel(int& counter, char ch) {
    std::string vowels{ "AaEeIiOoUu" };
    for (auto c : vowels)
        if(ch == c)
            counter++;
}

int main(){

    char ch;
    int counter{};
    while (std::cin >> ch)
        isVowel(counter, ch);

    std::cout << counter << endl << " vowels in this sentence." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isVowel(int vowels, char ch);
```

So `isVowel` returns a `bool`. That would make sense if its purpose was to tell us whether a single character was a vowel or not. For some reason, we pass an integer called `vowels` to it. That doesn't seem to make any sense. What would it do with an integer value?

```
int main() {
    char ch;
```

So `ch` is a single character. Okay.

```
    int vowels;
```

And `vowels` is an integer with no particular value.

```
    cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
    cin >> ch;
```

Uh oh. We ask the user to enter a sentence but then we read in a single character. Remember, `ch` was a `char`.

```
    ch = isVowel(vowels,ch);
```

Uh oh. We didn't assign `vowels` any particular value, so we've passed no particular value to `isVowel`. Also, we took the boolean value returned and assigned to a variable of type `char`. Why would we do that?

```
    cout << isVowel(vowels, ch) << " vowels in this sentence." << endl;
```

Then for some reason we call `isVowel` again. That doesn't make much sense. Also, `isVowel` returned a `bool` (a yes or no). Why are we outputting that as if it was the number of vowels?

```
    return 0;
}
// build a string counter and make it callable
bool isVowel(int vowels, char ch){
```

Okay, so `isVowel` returns a boolean and takes as input an integer and a character.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ch; i++){
     if (ch=='A' || ch=='E' || ch=='I' || ch=='O' || ch=='U' ||
        ch=='a' || ch=='e' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u'){
        vowels++;
  }
```

We are looping from zero to the value of the single character? That doesn't make sense.

```
 }
    return vowels;
}
```

Lots of problems here. Because there are so many fundamental problems with this code, it seems you've attempted a problem that's way beyond your C++ knowledge and you should attempt something much simpler first, such as accepting a sentence as input and repeating it back to the user without using any additional functions.

Comment: Look, man, I get it. I'm not good at this, whatsoever. However, I believe that you should attempt to address peoples shortcomings better than this here. From a look at your credentials it seems as if your extremely capable with many facets of programming. I'd be more than happy to employ you as a teacher/tutor. Thank your for your response because it shows me that I have miles to improve on.

Comment: @BrandonWadeTaylor This site is a question and answer site. I can't really do more here than answer the question you asked. I tried to do that the best I could. But it is clear that you are attempting tasks that vastly exceed your capability and that is a waste of your time. Trying to learn too many things at once leads to frustration and stalled learning. Attempting a much simpler problem would let you solve only one or two things at a time rather than figuring out how to get input, how to pass values to functions, how to get values back, how to iterate over a string, and so on all at once.

Comment: You're definitely right, sir. I hope you consider my offer, too, I could definitely use it. Thank you for your time.